# Activating an event function from the code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have this function, that is activated on a button click:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I want to use this function, also from another function in the code behind.

For example, like this:

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
button1_Click();
}
```

What do you send to `button1_Click` from `button2_Click` as my `sender` and `e`?
or is there another option to use it without sending anything somehow?

Comment: Move the logic from the event to a separate method, then call that from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doSomething();
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doSomething();
}

void doSomething()
{
   ...
}
```

If you "***must***" call it from `Button2_Click`, and you don't actually use the `sender` and `EventArgs`, then you can do this:

```
Button2_Click(null, null);
```